# SQL Query INNER JOIN with three tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join

There are these three tables:

1. posts
2. posts_replies
3. likes

This query is returning me posts and their replies count all fine.
SELECT posts.title, posts.num, posts.status, posts.category, posts.content, posts.member_num, COUNT( posts_replies.blyrb_num ) AS count

```
FROM posts_replies
INNER JOIN posts ON ( posts_replies.blyrb_num = posts.num )
WHERE posts.status =1
AND posts.access = 'Public'
GROUP BY posts.num
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Records this query is returning are: 47

And this is a bit updated query that i wanted to pull the Likes Count of each Reply on Posts.

```
SELECT posts.title, posts.num, posts.status, posts.category, posts.content, posts.member_num, 
COUNT( posts_replies.blyrb_num ) AS count,
COUNT( likes.comment_num  ) AS likes_count
FROM posts_replies
INNER JOIN posts ON ( posts_replies.blyrb_num = posts.num )
INNER JOIN likes ON ( likes.comment_num = posts_replies.num )
WHERE posts.status =1
AND posts.access = 'Public'
GROUP BY posts.num
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 50
```

This query is returning Likes Count fine, but not including those records which have no Likes. 
So the Records this query is returning are: 40

I want to include Likes Count of each reply, even if it has 0 likes.

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: Left Join not inner join. If you want it whether there is match or not

Comment: If you want to get rows from tables where there is no match, you need either a left or right join depending on which side the table is on from where you want to return the null records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` might help you here

```
SELECT posts.title, posts.num, posts.status, posts.category,
posts.content,posts.member_num, 
COUNT( posts_replies.blyrb_num ) AS count,
COUNT( likes.comment_num  ) AS likes_count
FROM posts_replies
INNER JOIN posts ON ( posts_replies.blyrb_num = posts.num )
LEFT JOIN likes ON ( likes.comment_num = posts_replies.num )
WHERE posts.status = 1
AND posts.access = 'Public'
GROUP BY posts.num
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 50
```

The idea of `LEFT JOIN` is to match rows even if there are none to be matched on the right side. `INNER JOIN` only works when both sides have rows. :)